# Concatenación de variables con strings

Tags: javascript, php7

Tengo este código para hacer una tabla a partir de una consulta SQL:

```
$tabla .="<tbody>";

try { 
    //pasar la consulta a la conexion
    $resultado=$conn->prepare($sql1);     
    $resultado->execute();


    while($row = $resultado->fetch()) {
        //Almacenar todos los datos en una cadena, separados cun una barra. Mas tarde los recogeré con Javascript y los separaré en valores individuales.

        $datos=$row[0]."/".$row[8]."/".$row[9]."/".$row[10]."/".$row[11];

        $tabla .="<tr>";
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[7].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[2].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[3].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td><button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVerBillete" onclick="cargaDatos('."$datos".')"></button></td>';
        $tabla .="</tr>";
    }
    //cierre del cuerpo y de la tabla
    $tabla .="</tbody>";
    $tabla .="</table>";

    echo $tabla;
```

El programa me esta devolviendo un error de tipo:

cargaDatos(4359797/28.1300/CARMELO/DIEZ)

acordeon.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CARMELO is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (acordeon.php:1)

Y creo que es porque los datos almacenados en la variable $datos son de distintos tipos (numeros y strings). Los estoy recogiendo concatenados en una cadena que más tarde separaré en Javascritp con la funcion valores=datos.split("/") pero es que ni siquiera llego allí. El código se detiene al pulsar el botón porque algo encuentra mal en la cadena pasada a la función.

onclick='cargaDatos(dato1/dato2/dato3/dato4)'

Agradezco la ayuda por adelantado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas concatenando mal.  Necesitas escapar las comillas simples.  Algo asi:

```
$tabla .='<td><button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVerBillete" onclick="cargaDatos(\''.$datos.'\')"></button></td>';
```

Comment: Correcto. Muchas gracias.